# Use of undefined constant accepted

Tags: php, html

Im getting this error:

```
  Whoops \ Exception \ ErrorException (E_NOTICE) 
  Use of undefined constant accepted - assumed 'accepted'
```

from this script

```
<script type="text/html" id="contactItemTemplate">
    <li class="list-group-item <% if (accepted) { %>contact-confirmed<% } %>" data-contact-id="<%= id %>">
        <a href="<?php echo App::url('profile.php?u=') ?><%= id %>" target="_blank">
        <img src="<%= avatar %>" class="contact-avatar"><%= name %></a>
        <span class="label label-danger"><?php _e('main.contact_request') ?></span>
        <div class="pull-right">
            <span class="confirmed"><a href="javascript:EasyLogin.confirmContact(<%= id %>)"><?php _e('main.confirm_contact') ?></a> |</span>
            <a href="javascript:EasyLogin.removeContact(<%= id %>)"><?php _e('main.remove') ?></a>
        </div>
    </li>
</script>
```

However this works fine on localhost. and works fine in all files just this file where there is this script code .
is there some thing wrong ?

In using php 5.6

Comment: Should be `if ($accepted)`

Comment: It "works fine" also when the contact is not confirmed?

Comment: @Viney $accepted will be undefined $accepted. it works fine on localhost "accepted 
 "but not the host

Comment: If it's undefined simply ensure that it always is set to a value.

Comment: ok i fixed it thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know why but i fixed it by commenting

```
    //ob_start();
```

ob_start() spunds like it bring problem in my site . it caused header already sent , i caused this error , commenting it everything works.

maybe its bug or something . hope this helps someone else.